# How to fit a regression model with repeatedly measured independent variable, but dependent variable is measured once?

Tags: regression, repeated-measures

In this study pregnant women were measured repeatedly (say 10 times) for their behavioral practices (food portion, exercise, blood pressure, etc) and followed until the delivery of the baby to measure the weight of the baby. I want to fit a model with the dependent variable of birth weight and independent variables of behavioral practices.

I know repeated measures ANOVA and mixed effect models, but all those models deal with repeated measures of dependent variable. How to fit a single measured dependent variable to repeated measured independent variables? By the way Q&A posted [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49027/multiple-regression-with-repeatedly-measured-independent-variables)  does not help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a great many options. For guidance, start by considering your theories of what affects the outcome: what individual measurements *or combinations of* those measurements do you suppose are driving changes in birth weights? Averages (perhaps in food portions)? Maxima (perhaps for blood pressure)? Totals (perhaps for exercise)? Trends? Variability? You could even develop rarefied statistics such as a regression coefficient of BP against exercise--almost anything goes. Either you have a theory that will tell you this, and you can test it, or you must settle for exploratory analysis.