How to establish statistical significance of changes in strength & direction of confounding/mediators/risk factors/effect modifiers for paired survey?
First of all, I'm new to Biostatistics (took one Intro to BioStats class more than a year ago), so please be patient with me :-) ...
I have a paired survey taken before (F0 survey) and after the pandemic (F2 survey). I am interested in examining the effect the pandemic had on the relationship between one ordinal dependent outcome: Respect-at-Work (or RS) and two independent ordinal variables: Job Satisfaction (or JS) and Intention-to-Leave the workplace (or ITL)?
I'm also examining the role several pre/post-pandemic covariates, i.e. confounding factors, mediators, risk factors and effect modifiers may have had on the above relationships. These variables are ordinal, nominal, continuous and binary. Now, I have the following null hypotheses.
1) The pandemic caused no changes in the relationship between RS and JS
2) The pandemic caused no changes in the relationship between RS and ITL.
3) The pandemic caused no changes in in the strength and direction of confounding factors,
mediators, risk factors and effect modifiers.
I believe I can establish the statistical significance (SS) of the first two null hypotheses using the Wilcoxon Signed Rank Test for non-parametric paired ordinals (correct???). But how can I do the same for the third hypothesis? I may have several options:
A) Treat the paired covariates as independent variables and perform appropriate tests for the paired variable types to establish SS. Is this valid?
               ... OR ...

B) Determine the changes in ordinal regression coefficients (for RS & JS and RS & ITL) before and after the co-variates and somehow determine the SS of these changes? Are the changes directly related to changes confounding factors, mediators, risk factors and effect modifiers?
Also, I'm not sure what set of tests to perform for SS with covariates.
ChatGPT keeps suggesting using Mixed effects models or Generalized Estimating Equations (GEE) for confounders. Time-varying mediation analysis for mediators using techniques like cross-lagged panel models, include interaction terms in the regression model for effect modifier, etc. stuff that is quite complex and frankly way above my head.
Not sure how accurate the suggested info is since ChatGPT can lie or be 'very enthusiastic' in
its response sometimes...Thanks!

Good question here. You’re asking a variation on a classic question of examining change v differences at follow-up. See if this clarifies it: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26529/help-with-change-scores-and-or-ancova-design
