# Change score analysis vs multiple regression

Tags: regression, predictor, pre-post-comparison

I have a pre-treatment (T1) and post-treatment (T2) DV measure, and 4 IVs.
I am interested in how (and which) IVs predict change in DV from pre- to post-treatment, or predict post-treatment outcome (I'm happy to answer either).

I'm currently doing a stepwise **multiple linear regression** of the 4 IVs and pre-treatment measurement, with post-treatment measurement as the DV.

However, I've received feedback from my supervisor that this is confusing as I've mentioned 'change' in my hypothesis, yet I am using an outcome rating at T2, in which case my regression is looking for predictors of outcomes at T2. He recommended there should be a "*separate* section for predicting CHANGE scores (T2-T1 scores)", and that I need to do **"change score analyses"**.

My questions are:

1. Should I just remove the word "change" entirely and keep to only this current regression i.e. "predictors of outcome measure"?
2. Or should I do BOTH this regression *and* the suggested additional section of predicting change scores? Does it make sense to do both, and would that add huge value to my thesis?
3. What is a change score analysis? How do I go about doing it? I did a repeated measures t-tests showing that change from pre- to post-test is significant, but apparently that's not what he was referring to.

Thank you SO very much for your help! I'm absolutely clueless and this has been giving me a massive headache. Any reply would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do both.  There's a substantial and complex literature comparing both methods, and results can vary surprisingly between the two, so you'll want to be aware of any difference.  Change score = gain score = T2 - T1.  Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/how-should-one-control-for-group-and-individual-differences-in-pre-treatment-sco