# Why do regression models predicting a change score vs. predicting T2 controlling for T1 yield slightly different results?

Tags: r, regression, residuals, pre-post-comparison

I am running multiple regression models testing whether a change from T1 to T2 in my IV predicts a change in my DV (also from T1 to T2). I am running these analyses in R using the glm function.

I ran the same model again in a slightly different manner, predicting change in my DV directly rather than by controlling for my DV at T1. However, this yields slightly different results. Why is this? I assumed the two models would be doing exactly the same thing, but apparently not. Both models also contain both my IV and my DV at two measurement points, so this can't be due to more missings in of the two models. Here is my R-code:

```
### Version 1: 
M0 <- glm(IV.t2 ~ IV.t1,
          data = data,
          na.action = na.omit)

Res_IV <- resid(M0)

M1 <- glm(DV.t2 ~ DV.t1 + Res_IV,
          data = data,
          na.action = na.omit)

### Version 2:
M0.1 <- glm(IV.t2 ~ IV.t1,
          data = data,
          na.action = na.omit)

Res_IV <- resid(M0.1)

M0.2 <- glm(DV.t2 ~ DV.t1,
          data = data,
          na.action = na.omit)

Res_DV <- resid(M0.2)

M2 <- glm(Res_DV ~ Res_IV,
          data = coronaUK_T1_T2_cost,
          na.action = na.omit)
```

**What might be the reason for these differences? Do the two analyses mathematically do something different?**

Comment: A contentious topic.  Addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26529/help-with-change-scores-and-or-ancova-design , https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17724/how-should-one-control-for-group-and-individual-differences-in-pre-treatment-sco , https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I follow your code, and how it relates to what you have in mind.

For starters, it's slightly odd that you are using `glm()` but aren't setting the `family` argument.  By default, `family=gaussian`, in which case, `glm()` fits a standard linear model, like what you would get by using `lm()`.  The differences are that `glm()` estimates the parameters by *searching* using a variant of the Newton-Raphson algorithm, instead of using ordinary least squares (OLS).  In addition, it tests the parameters using Wald $z$-tests, instead of $t$-tests.  In both cases, there are (slight) reasons to prefer the methods used by `lm()`.  Moreover, there are methods that operate over the output (e.g., `summary()`) that will provide more useful information if `lm()` was used.  Was this supposed to be a model for non-normal data (e.g., a binary response or a count)?

Second, neither of your models uses the difference between measures at time 1 and time 2, as far as I can tell.  Instead, you seem to be using the part of the time 2 measure that cannot be explained by knowledge of the time 1 measure.  That's not the same thing.  Consider this simple simulation (coded in `R`):

```
set.seed(5758)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible

t1  =             round(rnorm(6, mean=50, sd=10), digits=1)
t2  = 10 + 2*t1 + round(rnorm(6, mean=0,  sd=1),  digits=1)
dif = t2-t1
m   = lm(t2~t1)
round(coef(summary(m)), digits=2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)    10.00       1.66    6.03        0
# t1              2.01       0.03   64.71        0
res = residuals(m)
cor(dif,res)  # [1] 0.06151258
data.frame(t1, t2, dif, res)
#     t1    t2  dif         res
# 1 62.3 134.9 72.6 -0.07585836
# 2 64.6 140.4 75.8  0.81043618
# 3 58.2 125.4 67.2 -1.35142689
# 4 52.6 115.9 63.3  0.38194292
# 5 42.6  95.8 53.2  0.34153188
# 6 33.9  77.9 44.0 -0.10662574
windows(width=7, height=4)
  layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1))
  dotchart(t1, xlim=c(min(t1,t2),max(t1,t2)), cex=.8,
           main="Values\n(w/ differences implied)")
  axis(side=2, at=1:6, cex=.8)
  points(t2, 1:6, pch="+")
  plot(t1, t2, main="Scatterplot\n(w/ residuals implied)", cex.axis=.8)
  abline(coef(m), col="gray")
windows()
  plot(dif, res)
```

[image]

[image]

---

Setting that aside, we can ask if the answers have to / should be the same.  The answer is no.  Consider these simulations:

```
set.seed(2621)

y1c = rnorm(10, mean=100, sd=15)
y2c = y1c + rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)

y1d = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
y2d = rnorm(10, mean=5, sd=1)

round(coef(summary(lm(y2c~y1c))), digits=2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)     5.00       4.81    1.04     0.33
# y1c             0.95       0.05   20.76     0.00
round(coef(summary(lm(y2c-y1c~1))), digits=2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)      0.1       0.35    0.27     0.79

round(coef(summary(lm(y2d~y1d))), digits=2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)     4.97       0.48   10.29     0.00
# y1d            -0.08       0.55   -0.15     0.89
round(coef(summary(lm(y2d-y1d~1))), digits=2)
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
# (Intercept)     5.43       0.49   11.18        0
```

The short answer is that the two methods can give different answers because they correspond to different questions.  In general, regression models treat $X$ and $Y$ variables asymmetrically.  Specifically, $x$-values are taken to be *fixed and known*, whereas $y$-values are considered to be *a mix of true signal and random noise*.  Using change scores as your response, means that you are assuming the differences are a combination of input from $X$ and some pure randomness.  On the other hand, when you model time 2 values controlling for time 1 values, the time 1 values are treated as constants measured with perfect accuracy, and the time 2 values are partly stochastic error.

---

This leads to a third question, which should you use?  You should be aware that, as @rolando2 [points out](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465080/why-do-regression-models-predicting-a-change-score-vs-predicting-t2-controlling/465289#comment860108_465080), this is a very contentious topic in statistics.  There have been various camps in favor of each that have been fussing at each other for decades.  The threads he links to are worth reading to get some perspective.  If pressed, I suppose I would say you should use the method that best corresponds to your research question.

Comment: Recent article (https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Analyses-of-%27change-scores%27-do-not-estimate-causal-Tennant-Arnold/80020502d01c33746f83bba6aed1b216ac1fd110) by Tennant et al. (2021) on this topic arguing in favor of Y1 as a regressor based on causal graphs.